# Translating raw CAN responses into meaningful min/max/value

Tags: fuel-system, obd-ii, sensor, o2-sensor, gauges

http://www.scangauge.com/support/x-gauge/xgauges-for-cansf-vehicles/

This website lists data reported by certain sensors.
Lets take an example:

Gauge = Short Term Fuel Trim Bank 1

TXD = 07E00106

RXF = 044105060000

RXD = 2808

MTH = 00C80100FF9C

Name = SF1

Notes = +/- 0 to 99

Comparing with the Wiki page for OBD PIDs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs), Short Term Fuel Trim Bank 1 is Mode 01 PID 06.

How do I relate the data of Short Term Fuel Trim Bank 1 from XGauge website with the Wiki page. I mean how will be the formula, PID, max and min values, units be derived from the XGauge data?